# Can I generically specifiy a Method for a Go-Lang Struct?

Tags: go, go-interface

I have been reading over [the go-lang interface doc](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types) ; however it is still not clear to me if it is possible to achieve what I'd like

```
type A struct {
    ID SomeSpecialType
}

type B struct {
    ID SomeSpecialType
}

func (a A) IDHexString() string {
    return a.ID.Hex()
}

func (b B) IDHexString() string {
    return b.ID.Hex()
}
```

This will work fine; however I'd prefer some idiomatic way to apply the common  method to both types and only define it once.  Something Like:

```
type A struct {
    ID SomeSpecialType
}

type B struct {
    ID SomeSpecialType
}

func (SPECIFY_TYPE_A_AND_B_HERE) IDHexString() string {
    return A_or_B.ID.Hex()
}
```

Comment: You can't, but you could use embedding, so that embedding a `mypkg.ID` in any struct gives it the `IDHexString` method. Sadly I don't have time to write up details, but http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, using composition,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type ID struct{}

func (id ID) Hex() string { return "ID.Hex" }

func (id ID) IDHexString() string {
    return id.Hex()
}

type A struct {
    ID
}

type B struct {
    ID
}

func main() {
    var (
        a A
        b B
    )
    fmt.Println(a.IDHexString())
    fmt.Println(b.IDHexString())
}
```

Output:

```
ID.Hex
ID.Hex
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentialy you can't like you're used to, but what you can do is anonymously inherit a super-struct (sorry it's not the legal word :P):

```
type A struct {

}

type B struct {
    A // Anonymous
}

func (A a) IDHexString() string {

}
```

`B` will now be able to implement the `IDHexString` method.

This is like in many other languages kind of the same as:

```
class B extends A { ... }
```